# Simplify a product of annihilation/creation operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, operators

Take $\psi^\dagger(r) = \sum_i c^{\dagger}_i φ∗_i (r)$, $\psi(r) = \sum_i c_iφ_i(r)$, $c^\dagger_i$ and $c_i$ are fermionic creation/annihilation operators.

I want to calculate:
$\langle{0}|\psi(r2)\psi(r1)c^{\dagger}_ic^{\dagger}_j|0\rangle$

But how to simplify the product $c_{i'}c_{j'}c^{\dagger}_ic^{\dagger}_j$ obtained after replacing the expression of $\psi$? My lectures notes only provide the anticommutation relations and I don't see how to use it to find the final result $\phi_i(r1)\phi_j (r2) − \phi_j (r1)\phi_i(r2)$.

Comment: The second piece of information that your lecture notes should provide is that the incoming vacuum state is annihilated by the lowering operator $c_j$. I.e., $c_j|0\rangle =0 =\langle0| c_j^\dagger$.

Comment: I turned off my pc, realized this property, did the calculation, opened my pc back and saw your comment haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my question as I realized $c_j|0 \rangle=0$. So the idea is to invert creation and annihilation with the anticommutation by putting all annihilation on the right side so they cancel the vacuum. I am left with products of kroneker in the end.